# que devuelve un AND entre integers?

Tags: c#

Cual es la lógica que sigue. No llego a entender porque esto

```
int a = 0x0c;
a &= 0x05;
```

devuelve esto

```
4
```

entiendo los números hexadecimales solo que no entiendo la lógica del AND entre integers

Comment: [Operador & (Referencia de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/sbf85k1c.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si pasas los valores a binario

```
0x0C = 1 1 0 0
0x05 = 0 1 0 1
```

Y aplicas el operador lógico AND donde:

```
1 AND 1 = 1 
1 AND 0 = 0
0 AND 0 = 0
```

El resultado es:

```
      1 1 0 0
 AND  0 1 0 1 
      ------- 
      0 1 0 0
```

Que en decimal es = 4 y en hexadecimal = 0x04

Answer (score 1):

Una expresión que utiliza el operador de asignación &= por ejemplo x &= y  ,es equivalente a

> x = x & y

Tus numeros son Hexadecimales representando el 12 y 5 respectivamente

Comment: claro la pregunta se referia mas bien a la respuesta. Porque el and entre esos dos numeros da 4